# Playing Video from RTMPT Stream in JwPlayer

Tags: html, streaming, video-streaming, jwplayer, rtmp

I'm use JwPlayer to play video from Red 5 Media Server.

How do We play video which streamed via `RTMPT` protocol?

Thanks,

Comment: Not `RTMP` but RTMP that wrapped over HTTP (`RTMPT`).

Comment: Do you have a sample stream of one?